# useState hook not initialising with correct value: Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks

I am passing an array 'defaults' into my panel component and then trying to set state hook 'selected option' to be equal to it. For some reason, the hook is setting an empty array instead.

component:

```
const Panel = ({ title, inputs, datepicker, identifiers, apiBase, isins, defaults = [], notes = "" }) => {
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
    const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([...defaults]);
    const [dataError, setDataError] = useState(false);
    const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
    const [errorCheckLoading, setErrorCheckLoading] = useState(false);

    const toggleExpand = () => {
        setExpand(!expand);
        console.log(defaults);
        console.log(selectedOption);
    };
```

Just for testing, I have a couple of console logs in my toggle expand function so I can test the data passed in against the data set.

Output from console logs:

```
>(48) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
 {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, 
 {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
>[]
```

So I know the data comes in ok, just that it doesn't set in the hook.

I have also tried giving the hook initial values of defaults, and  [defaults].

Now drawing a blank - any ideas?

Edit: this is the parent component supplying the defaults:

```
const Parent = () => {

    const [all, setAll] = useState([]);
    const [allLoadFailed, setAllLoadFailed] = useState(false);

    const [defaults, setDefaults] = useState([]);
    const [defaultsLoadFailed, setDefaultsLoadFailed] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => { loadData()}, []);
    useEffect(() => { loadDefaultData()}, []);

    const loadDefaultData = async () => {
        try {
            let defaultData = await GetDefaults();
            setDefaults(defaultData.map(item => item = {value: item, label: item}));
        } catch (_) {
            setDefaultsLoadFailed(true);
        }
    };

    const loadData = async () => {
        try {
            let iData = await GetAll();
            let filteredIData = iData.filter(item => item);
            setAll(filteredIData.map(item => item = {value: item, label: item}));
        } catch (_) {
            setAllLoadFailed(true);
        }
    };


    return (

            <Panel
                title="Test"
                isins={all}
                defaults={defaults}
                inputs
                datepicker
                identifiers
                apiBase=""
                notes="not yet complete"
                key="2"
            />
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your destructuring, you're setting a default value to `defaults = []`. It will only render the empty array first and then the component will complete it's mount. You might want to use a `useEffect` hook to check for new updates and then set the `setSelectedOption(defaults)` in there like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
   setSelectedOption(defaults)
}, [defaults])
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing here that `defaults` is a value from api call?

This happens because in the initial render `defaults = []` and `useState`'s first parameter only get the initial value, so when `default` change to the correct data in the second render, the `useState` already have the `[]` value.

What you should do is use `useEffect` hook when `defaults` change and set `selectedOption`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setSelectedOption([...defaults])       
}, [defaults, setSelectedOption])
```

Comment: Oh great this works perfectly. I hadn't realised you could watch any value in the useEffect dependencies - in my head it was only state hooks. Nice, thanks.

Comment: hmmm, I just noticed this solution is triggering a 'maximum update depth exceeded' warning.

Maybe there is a re-render of the parent component being triggered, where the api call is made?

Comment: @It's because of the `if`

Comment: really? still happens even if i revert the solution to the below from @Claeusdev

Comment: @PeteG could you please share where `defaults` come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207984/discussion-between-peteg-and-vencovsky).